# How to pass dictionary to tensorflow py_func

Tags: python, tensorflow

While using tensorflow dataset API, map function accepts `lambda, python function`.

If the python function inside map makes a database call, the `py_func` can wrap the python function. `py_func` function throws up when `inp` arguments receives dictionary.

```
### Dict in Tensorflow
def parse(data):
    # Make some DB calls with data, but here just add the values.
    return data[0] + data[1]

iterator = tf.data.Dataset.range(10).map(
     lambda x: {0: [x * 2], 1: [x ** 2]}).map(lambda x: 
     tf.py_func(parse, inp=[x], 
        Tout=tf.int64)).make_initializable_iterator()

init_op = iterator.initializer
get_next = iterator.get_next()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init_op)
    print(sess.run(get_next))
```

Traceback

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 ~/miniconda3/envs/metadata/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py in make_tensor_proto(values, dtype, shape, verify_shape)
467     try:
--> 468       str_values = [compat.as_bytes(x) for x in proto_values]
469     except TypeError:

~/miniconda3/envs/metadata/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py in <listcomp>(.0)
467     try:
 --> 468       str_values = [compat.as_bytes(x) for x in proto_values]
469     except TypeError:

~/miniconda3/envs/metadata/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/compat.py in as_bytes(bytes_or_text, encoding)
 64     raise TypeError('Expected binary or unicode string, got %r' %
 ---> 65                     (bytes_or_text,))
      66 

TypeError: Expected binary or unicode string, got {0: <tf.Tensor 'arg0:0' shape=(1,) dtype=int64>, 1: <tf.Tensor 'arg1:0' shape=(1,) dtype=int64>}
```

The workaround is to pass the keys and values in a dictionary as separate arguments.

Can `py_func` pass dictionary as an argument for the calling function?

Tensorflow version == 1.4, Python == 3.5

Comment: I'm trying to run your sample, but in my case it doesn't go past the first `map`: `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get_shape'`

Comment: @GPhilo Which version of TF you're running? I'm on `1.4.0`

Comment: I'm on the latest, but AFAIK there was no change in `tf.data`'s interface since 1.4 (changelog doesn't mention anything, at least). Right now I can't really try this on 1.4 though

Comment: Python version 3.5. Thanks for trying.

Comment: `py_func` doesn't work with dictionaries, only with lists